# Get Tridion Item ID with from URI Regex

Tags: regex, tridion

If I have a Tridion URI like this 'tcm:1-23-8' and I want to get 23 with a Regular Expression.

The following works, but I know there is a better way.  tcm: and '-8' are always there.  The parts that change are 1 and 23.

```
var schemaUri = $display.getItem().getId(); // tcm:1-23-8
var re = /tcm:\d-/gi;  // = 23-8
var schemaIdWithItemType = schemaUri.replace(re, "");
re = /-8/gi;
var schemaId = schemaIdWithItemType.replace(re, "");
```

Comment: Check out the 'TcmUri' class in the DD4T project: http://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.ContentModel/ContentModel.cs

Comment: /-(\d+)-/ is close, but I get tcm:23.  I would like the tcm: stripped as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the number is *always*  between the 2 dashes, you could do this:

```
var schemaId = schemaUri.split('-')[1];
```

This does the following:

1. `split` the string on the `'-'` character --> `['tcm:1', '23', '8'];`
2. Get the second item from that array, `'23'`

Or, try this:

```
var schemaId = schemaUri.match(/-\d+-/)[0].replace(/-/g,'');
```

This'll find the number in between the dashes with `.match(/-\d+-/)`, then remove the dashes.

Comment: If you also need the Publication Id (the 1 after tcm:) then you can apply the same technique again: schemaUri.split(':')[1].split('-') and it will give you the array ['1', '23', '8']. I didn't test this though, but I think you get the idea :)

Answer (score 3):

Rather than calling `$display.getItem().getId();`, you can just call `$display.getUri();` and then use the `split()`

```
var schemaId = $display.getUri().split('-')[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

If you did want a pure Regex solution...

```
/^tcm:(\d+)-(\d+)(?:-(\d+))?$/i
```

Should validate your Tridion URI's format and provide you with 3 submatches, the second of which will be the Item ID

Comment: submatches are a nice touch since you could re-use the same expression to get publication and item type